# applescript - apply command (delete filetype) to all subfolders

Tags: applescript, subdirectory, file-type, finder

I'm trying to write a script that deletes all .tmp files in a chosen folder as well as all of its subfolders.

I currently have it set up as such:

```html
set sequenceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select a sequence:"


try
 
 tell application "Finder"
  
  set SubFolders to every folder of entire contents of sequenceFolder
  repeat with aFolder in SubFolders
   delete (every item of folder (sequenceFolder) whose name ends with ".tmp")
   delete (every item of folder (SubFolders) whose name ends with ".tmp")
   delete (every item of folder (aFolder) whose name ends with ".tmp")
   display dialog ("Files Deleted!") buttons {"OK"}
   
  end repeat
 end tell
 
 
 
on error
 
 display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Delete Files") buttons {"OK"}
 
 
 
end try
```

It currently works at deleting files in sequenceFolder but not any of the subfolders. I would also love for it to look for subfolders recursively, but I have no idea how. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the shell commands `find` and `rm` because they provide to consider all files in the given folder and its subfolders and it's so much faster than the Finder.

## **Caution:**

**The following code deletes all files with specified file extension in all folders and subfolders of the selected folder immediately without putting them in the trash folder**

```
set theFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Please select a sequence:")
do shell script " /usr/bin/find " & quoted form of theFolder & "  -name '*.tmp' -exec rm {} \\;"
display dialog ("Files Deleted!") buttons {"OK"}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to make a shell command use the prompted file path, so this is perfect.